# YARN - get the name of all nodes

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am developing a YARN application. I want my ApplicationMaster to get the names of all node (=table of the hosts) on the cluster. How can I do that ?

Note that I might be able to pass it from the client if it is possible to get it from the Client.